# Issue with conditionally moving records to new wksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I started making a script to help me create worksheets based on data. I have a summary sheet with data sorted by client name. If the client only has one record, then it needs to be on its own worksheet. If the client has multiple records all the records must be on 1 worksheet. I ran the code below, but it still puts all clients on their own sheet.

Create_WB()

```
Sub Create_WB()
    'duplicate worksheet and assign it to variable 'wb'
    Dim wb As Worksheet
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set wb = ActiveSheet

    'copy data over
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").Copy wb.Range("A10")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Copy wb.Range("A11")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2").Copy wb.Range("C14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("D2").Copy wb.Range("A14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("E2").Copy wb.Range("E14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("F2").Copy wb.Range("G14")

    'delete row from summary
    Worksheets("Summary").Rows(2).Delete

End Sub
```

Check_CM()

```
Sub Check_CM()

    'statement to check if next record has same c/m
    Do While Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2") <> ""
    '
    '
    If Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2") <> Worksheets("Summary").Range("A3") Then
         Call Create_WB


    Else

        Rows(14).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").Copy wb.Range("A10")
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Copy wb.Range("A11")
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2").Copy wb.Range("C14")
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("D2").Copy wb.Range("A14")
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("E2").Copy wb.Range("E14")
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("F2").Copy wb.Range("G14")
    '
    '
    '
    End If


    Loop

End Sub
```

I want all records with same client to be on same sheet but every record has its own sheet.

Comment: You're calling `Create_WB` within your loop, this appears to creating new sheet each time. However, the code within the `Else` condition will raise some errors, as `wb` object instance is not assigned within scope of the `Check_CM` subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

*--- Disclaimer ---*

Here is some code I wrote back when I first started learning VBA.

Looking back I can see many opportunities for improvement. However, this has worked for me with no issues (although that could be because of that shameful `On Error Resume Next` line that I added). Since this works as is, I will leave the fine-tuning to you!

---

This will create a new sheet (one for every unique value in `Column A`) and then move all of the associated data from each unique value to it's respective sheet.

This assumes

1. Raw Data is on `Sheet1`
2. Your unique values span `Column A`
3. You header is on `Row 1` and your data starts on `Row 2`

---

```
Sub parse_data()

Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row

' A1:Q5000 only needs to be modified if more than 4999 rows of data exists.

title = "A1:Q5000"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it

```
Sub Create()
'duplicate worksheet and assign it to variable 'wb'
Dim wb As Worksheet
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set wb = ActiveSheet
End Sub

Sub Copy()
'copy data over
Set wb = ActiveSheet
Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").Copy wb.Range("A10")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Copy wb.Range("A11")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2").Copy wb.Range("C14")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("D2").Copy wb.Range("A14")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("E2").Copy wb.Range("E14")
Worksheets("Summary").Range("F2").Copy wb.Range("G14")

End Sub



Sub Del()
'delete row from summary
Worksheets("Summary").Rows(2).Delete






End Sub

Sub Update()


End Sub





Sub Check_CM()

Call Create


'statement to check if next record has same c/m

' while summary is not blank run pgm
Do While Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2") <> ""
'set active sheet
Set wb = ActiveSheet
'if c/m is not same as active sheet cm
If Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2") <> wb.Range("A10") Then
     Call Create
     Call Copy
     Call Del




Else
    ' Set active sheet
    Set wb = ActiveSheet

    'Shift Cells Down to add another row
    Rows(14).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'copy data
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").Copy wb.Range("A10")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Copy wb.Range("A11")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2").Copy wb.Range("C14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("D2").Copy wb.Range("A14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("E2").Copy wb.Range("E14")
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("F2").Copy wb.Range("G14")

    'delete data from summary sheet
    Call Del

'
'
'
End If


Loop





End Sub
```